# Comparing just dates from DateTime C#

Tags: c#, wpf

My table contains 2 fields with values,

```
StartTime                 EndTime
  3/6/2010 8:00:00 AM       3/6/2010 10:20:00 AM
```

Now I have a datepicker control wherein the user can select a date,

```
C# Logic:
DateTime SelDate;
            if (datePicker.SelectedDate == null)
                SelDate = DateTime.Now; 
            else
                SelDate = datePicker.SelectedDate;
```

I am trying to compare dates by the below code but it gives me compile time error,

```
foreach (DomainObject obj in res.ResultSet)
                    {
                        MyClass adef = (MyClass)obj;
                        DateTime sTime = (DateTime)adef.StartTime;
                        DateTime eTime = (DateTime)adef.EndTime;

                        if ((SelDate.ToShortDateString >= sTime.ToShortDateString) && (SelDate.ToShortDateString <= eTime.ToShortDateString))
                        {
                            actdef.Add(new MyClassViewModel(adef));
                        }

                    }
```

I just want to take the date for comparison and not the time part. So I have used the ToShortDateString method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of `DateTime`:

```
if (SelDate.Date >= sTime.Date)
```

Also note that you can use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) to get the start of today.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Date property of the DateTime and do a straight comparison.

```
DateTime SelDate = datePicker.SelectedDate == null ? DateTime.Now : datePicker.SelectedDate;

if( SelDate.Date >= sTime.Date )
{
   // do something here
}
```